# CG: what's wrong with my per-pixel lighting?

Tags: directx, pixel-shader, cg

i try to do basic n-dot-l lighting in unity and CG.

to my understanding the lighting should not change depending from where you look at the object with your camera. but in my situation it does.

```
        struct v2f {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float3 LightDirection:   TEXCOORD2;
         float3 Normal:   TEXCOORD3;
        };

        uniform float4 _LightPos;

        v2f vert (appdata_tan v)
        {
            v2f o;

            o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.Texcoord = v.texcoord;

            float3 p = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex);

            o.LightDirection = _LightPos.xyz - p;

            o.Normal = v.normal;

            return o;
        }

        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            float3 l = normalize(i.LightDirection);
            float3 n = normalize(i.Normal);
            float x = dot(n,l);
            return float4(x,x,x,1);
        }
```

so what am i missing in this code?

do i need to transform the lights position with the modelview matrix as well?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v.normal` is in object space while `i.LightDirection` is in view space.

Pick a space and stick to it. Transforming normals to view space is one way to go. It requires to multiply by the inverse-transpose of the modelview. Depending on your model-view model, it can be as simple as the 3x3 upper part of the modelview.

Comment: thanks! so i tried assigning the normal like this: o.Normal = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, float4(v.normal,1)); but it still gives me strange results when i move the camera around.

Comment: @clamp: well... "strange" is not very descriptive.

Comment: well, the lighting intensity changes when i move the camera around. i think it should not.

Comment: also it seems the problem is with the lightpos. because if i visualize only the light as color on the model, it also changes when the camera is moved.

Comment: @clamp: well, that makes sense. The light direction is view dependent if the light stays in the same location world-space. Same for the normal. Only n.l stays the same.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. still even after n dot l the lighting changes if the camera is moved.